# Jenkins: How to build right after merging pull requests?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using [ghprb](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb) plugin to build the PRs. I want to build the master right after a PR is merged (since I want to package the project and  deploy artifacts to a repository).

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

- periodically by polling github repo (don't do that), or
- by triggering the job in a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

The Jenkins [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) allows you to trigger builds for a specific repo by posting to `http://jenkins.example.com/git/notifyCommit?url=<repo-url>`. You may need to write the piece that receives the webhook notification and translates it into a proper http request on your Jenkins server.